# custom form validation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, submit

I want to validate few inputs before submiting the form, i am doing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_arc_packages').submit(function(e){ /*should i use focus or similar, here?*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if(validarFormulario()==true){
            $('#form_arc_packages').submit(); /*Am i starting an infinite loop, here?*/
        }
    });
});
```

where

```
function validarFormulario(){       
        var valido = true;
        $('.errorCanc').slideUp();
        var fecha1=$('#date1').val();
        var fecha2=$('#date2').val();
        var area1=$('#area1').val();
        var area2=$('#area2').val();

        if (fecha1.length < 1){     $('#date1').next('.errorCanc').slideDown();     valido = false;     }
        if (fecha2.length < 1){  $('#date2').next('.errorCanc').slideDown();        valido = false;     }
        if (area1.length < 1){  $('#area1').next('.errorCanc').slideDown();     valido = false;     }   
        if (area2.length < 1){  $('#area2').next('.errorCanc').slideDown();     valido = false;     }   

        return valido;
}
```

Just checking the lenght of the inputs, for now, but the problem is that the form won't be submited (even when all inputs are set and with console.log i am making sure that validarFormulario returns true),

EDIT

And like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form_arc_packages').submit(function(e){ 
            if(validarFormulario()==true){
                $('#form_arc_packages').submit(); 
            }else{
                //Post didn't pass validation, so prevent posting
                e.preventDefault(); return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Seems to work ok in Firefox but for example, in IE7, it shows the errors (with the slideDown) and then stills submit the form... -EDIT- ignore this, it happened because of the `console.log()` i was using. works fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_arc_packages').submit(function(e){        
        if(validarFormulario()==false){
            e.preventDefault();
        }            
    });
});
```

Comment: From what you say there is an error in the validator code in IE and this stops the javascript execution, thus you never return false and so the form submits. You should correct the error relative to the slideDown in IE and everything should work

Comment: Is `validarFormulario()` returning true or false in IE?

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` preventing u ,change it to last line.

Comment: if(validarFormulario()==true){
   $('#form_arc_packages').submit();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); ??

Comment: try what Nicola Peluchetti said ,`return false`[JQ] or preventdDefault

Answer (score 1):

I think you are always preventing the default action , you should prevent it only if you don't pass validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_arc_packages').submit(function(e){ /*should i use focus or similar, here?*/      
        if(validarFormulario()==true){
            $('#form_arc_packages').submit(); /*Am i starting an infinite loop, here?*/
        }else{//Post didn't pass validation, so prevent posting
             return false;
        }
    });
});
```